# why file path of uploaded file is undefined ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asyncfileupload

I have ajax Async File Upload Control in asp.net, inside update panel. I have called javascript function on it to get filename of uploaded file but it always give ***Undefined text***. Why ?

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="FileUpload1" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" ClientIDMode="AutoID" UploaderStyle="Modern" runat="server"/>
asp:HiddenField ID="HdnFieldEmployeePicture" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="Static" ID="HdnFieldHasFileUploaded" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="Static" ID="UploadedFilePath" runat="server" />
```

calling this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
            var myHidden = document.getElementById('<%= HdnFieldHasFileUploaded.ClientID %>');
            myHidden.value = '1';

            var fu1 = args.get_fileName();
            UploadedFilePath.value = fu1.value;

        }
    </script>
```

**`fu1`** is always UNDEFINED, why ?

Comment: And what does this `get_fileName` function do ?

Comment: @adeneo "[\[R\]eturns the name of the file being uploaded](http://blogs.wrox.com/2009/10/21/enter-the-asyncfileupload-control/)

Comment: Then it should just be a matter of replacing `fu1.value` with just `fu1`